# Calling an action creator from within resolved promise

Tags: reactjs, flux

I've read many questions about when/where to make ajax requests, but I haven't seen any answers or questions about making the request from within a component (when it is mounted) and having the action creator called when the promise is resolved (or rejected).  Is this a bad way to approach populating/updating a store?  If so, what is the benefit of making the request from within the action creator itself?

Answer (score 1):

From my own observation, one of the benefits of making api requests in the actions rather than the components is to keep the components pure to make it easy to manage the state of your application. Components should share data only within themselves, only the parent components should know of any data coming from an external source. You should check out [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), it promotes this idea clearly.